# C# greedy regular expression including match text

Tags: c#, .net, regex, regex-greedy

I currently have the string:

```
"CL,UP_REMOVE_LINE,#global_session_id,arg_stage=false,arg_project_id=-1,#global_line_id,arg_activity_id=-1,arg_mode=1,arg_line_id=#global_line_id,arg_session_id=-1"
```

I tried:

```
splitty = Regex.Split(lineText,@"[\,]+\s*(?>arg_){1}?");
```

and received:

```
{string[7]}
    [0]: "CL,UP_REMOVE_LINE,#global_session_id"
    [1]: "stage=false"
    [2]: "project_id=-1,#global_line_id"
    [3]: "activity_id=-1"
    [4]: "mode=1"
    [5]: "line_id=#global_line_id"
    [6]: "session_id=-1"
```

I am splitting by at least one comma, followed by arbitrary white space followed by the "arg_" delimiter, but is there any way to keep the "arg_" portion intact, i.e. indicies [1-6]?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a positive lookahead (to check the presence of, but not consume, thus leaving it in the split chunks) instead of an atomic group (that is still consumed, and thus is removed when using `Split`):

```
,+\s*(?=arg_)
```

See the [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%2C%2B%5Cs*(%3F%3Darg_)&i=CL%2CUP_REMOVE_LINE%2C%23global_session_id%2Carg_stage%3Dfalse%2Carg_project_id%3D-1%2C%23global_line_id%2Carg_activity_id%3D-1%2Carg_mode%3D1%2Carg_line_id%3D%23global_line_id%2Carg_session_id%3D-1)

Note you do not need to put the comma into a character class, nor do you need to escape the comma.

[image]

Also, `{1}?` = `{1}` and is totally redundant (you may always remove it since this `{1}` is always implied (i.e. `abc` = `a{1}b{1}c{1}`)).

Comment: Perfect, thank you. So my greedy solution won't work because it consumes what it matches. I was under the opposite assumption on 'Nonbacktracking (or "greedy") subexpression' entry from https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az24scfc(v=vs.110).aspx where [13579](?>A+B+) yields
"1ABB", "3ABB", and "5AB" in "1ABB 3ABBC 5AB 5AC". Can you explain in this case why the greedy solution seems to do the opposite of our current assumption?

Comment: Atomic groups only "turn off" backtracking into a subexpression, they still match and consume text, while lookarounds do not consume the characters, they only check the presence or absence of some text before or after the current position *without* moving the index. See [*Mastering Lookahead and Lookbehind*](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-lookarounds.html): *It is that at the end of a lookahead or a lookbehind, the regex engine hasn't moved on the string. You can chain three more lookaheads after the first, and the regex engine still won't move.*